# Регулярные выражения Python - идем обратно

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите, пожалуйста, следующий момент насчет регулярных выражений.
Ранее я всегда пользовался ими следующим образом: брал искомое слово или фразу и далее от него шел по тексту и вытаскивал необходимые значения.
Сейчас мне необходимо сделать то же самое: найти ключевое слово, но двигаться не вперед по тексту, а обратно.

Пример:

```
"Заключение:
1
2
3
Подпись"
```

Мне надо оттолкнуться от `Подпись` и идти вверх по тексту, чтобы достать значения `3, 2, 1`.

Каким образом это можно сделать?

Comment: Этого не нужно делать. `re.search(r'(?m)^(\d[\d\s]*)^Подпись', s).group(1).split()` ([демо](https://ideone.com/h9zNX2))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всегда, когда кажется, что нужно "найти ключевое слово, но двигаться не вперед по тексту, а обратно", нужно подумать о том, как "найти все подстроки, удовлетворяющие нужному шаблону, после которых следует ключевое слово". Некоторые библиотеки регулярных выражений могут начинать поиск с конца строки к её началу, при этом не инвертируя текст, т.е. направление чтения шаблонов в регулярке остается неизменным - слева направо.

Таким образом, в данном случае проблема такова: найти все числа, которые разделены символом перевода строки, вплоть до строки, начинающейся со слова Подпись.

Используйте для  первого такого совпадения ([демо](https://regex101.com/r/dkG6fI/2)):

```
print(re.search(r'(?m)^(\d[\d\r\n]*)^Подпись', s).group(1).split())
```

Или все возможные подстроки:

```
print(re.findall(r'(?m)^\d+(?=[\d\r\n]*^Подпись)', s))
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/dkG6fI/1)

См. [демо](https://ideone.com/f2sVSJ) на Python.

В первом примере `(?m)^(\d[\d\r\n]*)^Подпись` находит начало строки (или позицию после перехода строки), затем захватывает любую цифру и 0+ переходов строки или цифр, а затем находит `Подпись` в начале строки. Затем значение первой подгруппы разбивается по пробельным символам.

Во втором случае ищутся все цифры от начала строки, за которыми следуют 0+ цифр или переходов строки, за которыми следует слово `Подпись`.

Comment: В данном конкретном примере понятно, а вот если попробовать применить его к реальному тексту, то не совсем получается. 

"Заключение:

ЭНМГ признаки демиелинизирующей мото-сенсорной полинейропатиии исследованных нервов нижних конечностей.

Снижение рефлекторной возбудимости сегмента S1 с двух сторон.

Врач функциональной диагностики"

Необходимо вытащить абзацы до "Врач функциональной диагностики". Их может быть сколько угодно.
От "Заключение:" оттолкнуться не получится, потому что оно не всегда присутствует в тексте.

Comment: @ВикторШамаков Вы сравните свой комментарий с вопросом - это две разные вещи. Зачем было спрашивать то, что вам не надо? Возможно, вам нужно [`(?s)(.*?)Врач функциональной диагностики`](https://regex101.com/r/tEDVn5/1), но я бы подумал тут о том, что проще было бы читать файл построчно и пока строка не начинается с `Врач функциональной диагностики`, добавлять их к результату.